# Using qbwc protocol on a web page

Tags: javascript, quickbooks

Have anybody succeeded in interacting directly with Web Connector using 
qbwc:///? stuff ?
I created a small page which calls these custom scheme URL with Ajax

```js
        function CheckQWCLoaded() {
            var strURL = 'qbwc://docontrol/WSExists?AppName=Quickbooks+to+eUnify+Integration?';
            var CheckResult = false;
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: strURL,
                dataType: "json",
                complete: function (XMLHTTP) {
                    if (XMLHTTP.status == 200) CheckResult = jQuery.parseJSON(XMLHTTP.responseText);
                }
            });
            return CheckResult;
        }
```

But when I run it in IE I get 'Access denied' error.
How can I grant permissions to my JS ?

Thanks,

Slava

Comment: Were you able to use QB Web Connector interactive mode successfully? I am looking into it myself, but there is not much documentation.

Comment: I know this post is old, but I'm getting the same message and was wondering if anyone figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: It is a plugin which handles qbwc protocol. I did it long time ago by changing some security setting of IE. I'll write if I find it. (I deleted all my mail after they deprived me of my QB project, it was there)

Comment: It needs to put host to trusted sites and lower security level for them.